# APFS encrypted volume, how to get actual free disk space

Tags: disk-utility, disk-space, apfs

I have a APFS volume running macOS Mojava. When I right click on the volume and click `Get Info` it shows:

[image]

Which in iteslf is confusing because available says 73.99 GB, but used shows all the disk is used 211 GB.

Even more confusing, when I run the unix command `df -h` command it outputs:

```sh
MacBook-Pro ➜ df -h
Filesystem      Size   Used  Avail Capacity iused               ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk1s1   233Gi  197Gi   34Gi    86% 2991853 9223372036851783954    0%   /
```

So `df` says I have 34 GB available.

What is the actual amount of free disk space I have? Also, how do I reclaim space and purge the disk?

Comment: No, you are misreading something. The image you show has Capacity = 250.69 GB.  Sounds like all numbers are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Your disk has a capacity of 250.69 GB with 211.9 GB used leaving 38.8 GB.  The reported free space is 74 GB but 37.5 is purgeable. Purgeable space on a Mac is space that the Mac considers save to clean up. So while it says you have 74 GB available, 37.5 GB is currently in use but is safe to erase and clear off..